# JavaFX trigger object creation at runtime from a distinct thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, javafx

I have two threads, each one having its own function: one deals with reading input from a socket and the other one is a GUI related thread (uses JavaFX).

The reading thread contains a reference to the Runnable object that the GUI thread was created from. When the reading thread receives an object of a certain type, it calls a method from the GUI thread.

This method should create a new Button labeled with some text that was received through the socket. However, then trying to instantiate a new Button, I get the following exception:

`Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4`.

I mention that when I try to update an existing component everything works fine and this exception is not thrown anymore, so I concluded that the object creation is what triggers the exception.

Is it possible to command the instantiation of a class from a different thread (as described above)? If not, are there any workarounds to achieve the same result?

Thank you!

Comment: A) general note on how to ask: whenever you describe a problem with "when doing this then that/when doing something else then something other happens" you _must_ provide a [mcve] that demonstrates that behaviour. B) general note on how-to start solving such problems: simply type the error message into your favorite search engine ;) And then, when none of the suggested solutions seems to fit to your specific context - take the one that's nearest to use for note A ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has probably already been asked a thousand times and is a fundamental aspekt of JavaFX programming. Adding (not creation of) controls to the GUI has to be done from the application thread. So if you want to initiate that from some other thread you have to wrap your call into a `Platform.runLater()` call.

Comment: Thank you, `Platform.runLater()` does what I need. However, instead of saying that this question has been asked for a thousand times, you could have provided a SO link to one of those posts. I decided to ask here only after searching for similar problems and not finding anything helpful...

Comment: Sorry if my answer sounded a bit rude but is it really so difficult to just use the relevant part of your exception message in the search function? I get 38 results for "IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread" and already the first of these mentions Platform.runLater().

Comment: arrghh .. that's really cross: @Polb you are too lazy to do the most simple search with whatever search engine but feel like critizising somebody who had the mercy to at least push you into the right direction? If you really did try and didn't find anything you have to refine your search strategies .. or do something else than software at all.

Comment: @kleopatra Please read my response again. First of all, I said 'Thank you', I upvoted his result so other know it is helpful and I did not criticize anyone. I wanted to emphasize fact that SO makes it available for users to signal a question as being duplicate, as well as providing a reference to the duplicate which already has an answer. It would have been more simple than debating whether my search engine is good or not. Please also note that I sticked to the question subject, unlike you, who felt that it is appropriate to question my software skills. This is not how SO works.